# dictionary reading from module

Tags: python, dictionary, module

I have following module root_file.py. This file contains number of blocks like.

```
Name = {
'1':'a'
'2':'b'
'3':'c'
}
```

In other file I am using

```
f1= __import__('root_file')
```

Now the requirement is that I have to read values `a,b,c` at runtime using variables like
for reading `a`

```
id=1
app=Name
print f1[app][id]
```

but getting error that

```
TypeError: unsubscriptable object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
import root_file as f1

id = 1
app = 'Name'
print getattr(f1, app)[id] # or f1.Name[id]
```

Comment: thanks that is working for me can you tell me that what is the difference between import root_file as f1 and f1=__import__('root_file')

Comment: former looks cleaner, isn't it.

Comment: thats ok but any technical difference

Answer (score 1):

Uh, well, if I understand what you are trying to do:

In root_file.py

```
Name = {
 '1':'a', #note the commas here!
 '2':'b', #and here
 '3':'c', #the last one is optional
}
```

Then, in the other file:

```
import root_file as mymodule
mydict = getattr(mymodule, "Name")
# "Name" could be very well be stored in a variable
# now mydict eqauls Name from root_file
# and you can access its properties, e.g.
mydict['2'] == 'b' # is a True statement
```